# How to parse actual HTML from page using CURL?

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I am "attempting" to scrape a web page that has the following structures within the page:

```
<p class="row">
    <span>stuff here</span>
    <a href="http://www.host.tld/file.html">Descriptive Link Text</a>
    <div>Link Description Here</div>
</p>
```

I am scraping the webpage using curl:

```
<?php
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.host.tld/");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
?>
```

I have done some research and found that I should not use a RegEx to parse the HTML that is returned from the curl, and that I should use PHP DOM. This is how I have done this:

```
$newDom = new domDocument;
$newDom->loadHTML($html);
$newDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$sections = $newDom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$nodeNo = $sections->length;
for($i=0; $i<$nodeNo; $i++){
    $printString = $sections->item($i)->nodeValue;
    echo $printString . "<br>";
}
```

Now I am not pretending that I completely understand this but I get the gist, and I do get the sections I am wanting. The only issue is that what I get is only the text of the HTML page, as if I had copied it out of my browser window. What I want is the actual HTML because I want to extract the links and use them too, like so:

```
for($i=0; $i<$nodeNo; $i++){
    $printString = $sections->item($i)->nodeValue;
    echo "<a href=\"<extracted link>\">LINK</a> " . $printString . "<br>";
}
```

As you can see, I cannot get the link because I am only getting the **text** of the webpage and not the **source**, like I want. I know the "curl_exec" is pulling the HTML because I have tried just that, so I believe that the DOM is somehow stripping the HTML that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to comments on [the PHP manual on DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), you should use the following inside your loop:

```
    $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument();
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($sections->item($i), true));
    $innerHTML = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());
```

This will set `$innerHTML` to be the HTML content of the node.

But I think what you really want is to get the 'a' nodes under the 'p' node, so do this:

```
$sections = $newDom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$nodeNo = $sections->length;
for($i=0; $i<$nodeNo; $i++) {
    $sec = $sections->item($i);
    $links = $sec->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $linkNo = $links->length;
    for ($j=0; $j<$linkNo; $j++) {
        $printString = $links->item($j)->nodeValue;
        echo $printString . "<br>";
    }
}
```

This will just print the body of each link.

Comment: You can also iterate over the nodes using `foreach` instead of the `for` loops. That will make it more compact and understandable, since you do not actually (seem to) need any of the indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a node to [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.savexml). Try this:

`$printString = $newDom->saveXML($sections->item($i));`

Comment: Yes, this will effectively return the `outerHTML` of the node

Comment: Apparently, the poster wanted the inner HTML, not the outer. That was not clear to me, but I will leave my answer up for the `saveXML` reference, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Manual) for doing server-side HTML parsing things. [basic example](http://phpquery-library.blogspot.com/2008/10/basic-example-demophp.html)