# its possible to display different categories from another site?

Tags: joomla2.5

Im working a newspaper, and I was wondering if its possible to display different categories from another Website, and display in my website. This site created by Joomla 2.5, I Hope someone understands this :)

Comment: You mean content from other categories from another website?

Comment: yes! you are right. @ValentinDespa

Comment: Is your site the Joomla one or is the other site the Joomla one?  If the other site is not Joomla, do you know what platform it is built on (or could you provide URL)?

Comment: my site made by joomla 2.5 and it is under construction @DanU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your site is the Joomla one, you could either write a custom extension or more simply use the [Jumi extension](http://2glux.com/projects/jumi) so you can write PHP code directly in the article or page on which you need to grab the content from the other site.

Then depending on what you know about the other site, there are different approaches.  If it offers an API or RSS feed, you can use that to pull the content you need (and use PHP string functions for instance to modify it as you need).  If the other site doesn't have an obvious way of offering content through a web service, try [PHP curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), and again you can modify the content before displaying it.  Check out this page too: [How to parse actual HTML from page using CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409264/how-to-parse-actual-html-from-page-using-curl)

As Arunu said an iFrame could also work if you don't need to modify the other site's content.

Answer (score 0):

What u wish to do can be accomplished using RSS feed or an i-frame.But from ur question 
it's not clear which site is using joomla.

Comment: my site made by joomla 2.5